# Best way to manage ios and android applications simultaneously

Tags: android, ios

When I build a web application, like most others, I simply build an admin area from which the client can control their site.

Most applications I build for android never require this kind of maintenance as they are all self contained. However Something I'm extremely curious about, say you build a cross platform application that does require constant maintenance; you've got 2 versions - an iOS and android version. What would be the best way to go about managing both applications from the same place?

For examples sake, let's say you build a real simple  application. It could be something that once a day sends you a message, "hope you're day is going well" or "let me tell you a joke". Now what if those messages were hand typed and submitted to the applications, you want to log into a system, type the daily message in and both applications are simultaneously updated with the new message.

In my head I'm imagining you would need to build a dedicated admin system either as a web application or standalone desktop application that connects to the apps hosted database however I'm wondering about how well that would work, what kind of problems are you going to run Into, would it even be feesable?

I've never had to build something like this but some of the more recent web applications I've built would work well as straight forward applications and that just gets me thinking, if I was asked to turn them into apps that function the way they do already, what would be the best way?

It's something I'm really curious about and feel like I need to get my understanding on the right track.

Comment: i think u just need to have a web server and application on server to handle API requests from both apps.

Comment: Yeah, in my head this is how I imagine it working. A simple PHP web application with simple CRUD operations to the database. I guess I'm overthinking it all but I would be interested to understand it in more depth, understand how others are achieving it.

Comment: Most business apps (banking, online shop) does this way too. it's a common setup. for banking, they will have extra security features like encryption of all sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing an application for an admin that will set up (write) data to be used by users of Android and IOS apps. Few options:

1. Write the admin application as a regular web application. Be careful to use transactions in the code that writes to the database. That is to avoid inconsistent DB states when your admin applications DB writes interleave between mobile app reads. Also you have to secure the admin REST resources (API end points) for admin access only, so you would need authorization code in the app.
2. Write admin apps for the mobile platforms (or an admin section in the existing app that is properly authorized in the app code) and the server API end points. That is more tedious because of 2 platforms. Again you will need the DB transactions and authorization code
3. Write separate admin apps for mobile but with one framework (Xamarin). It will work for simple apps and yours sounds simple enough for Xamarin to work well.

Comment: This is really helpful information, at the moment this is all hypothetical and really I'm just looking for some pointers to set me on a path where I know what I need to learn when the time is right. I think In my head I imagine it with the, web application, PHP system that uses restful crud operations. I really appreciate your answer and giving me some food for thought. Thank you!

Comment: glad you found it useful!